# Multiple methods named 'setTransform:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have an array in obj - c
the code

`NSArray *buttonViews = @[_aboutMeView , _educationView , _appsView , _skillsView];`

all these views are UIView

i define a for loop

```
 for(int i=0; i < [buttonViews count]; i++){
        [buttonViews[i] setCenter: self.wwdcView.center]; 
        // I get the error here
        [buttonViews[i] setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)];
    }
```

but then i get a build error.

Multiple methods named 'setTransform:' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes

Answer (score 3):

The type of the object returned by `objectAtIndex:` (which is what `buttonViews[i]` calls is `id`.   The compiler sees two declarations of `setTransform:` that take different parameter types and complains.

This would be better:

```
 for(UIView *buttonView in buttonViews) {
     [buttonView ...];
 }
```

You could also declare buttonViews as type `NSArray <UIView *>*`.

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it, but you could also cast (UIView *) in front of buttonView[i] to tell the compiler to specifically use UIView's setTransform opposed to another classes method. It's good to know the casting option for other use cases.

Comment: Don't edit your question and make existing answers no longer relevant.  Post a new question.

Comment: @gregyoung14 Casting would work, but I try to avoid casting wherever possible.